# GPS Location in iOS in the building premises or under parking area

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get the location in the iOS device through "`CLLocationManager`".
As per current implementation I get proper location with speed too if iOS device is outside building premises.

When device is moved in the building or in the parking area, it not working i tried to change the `desiredAccuracy` to *`kCLLocationAccuracyBest`,  `kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters` and kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters.*
Still its not able to work and nor the delegate (call back)

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

is called.

Please let me know if any solution to get the location in this case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is typical problem with GPS adapters. They don't work well in buildings.

Comment: You are not getting delegate callback, because device GPS is not able to find a valid location. try to debug the failedWithError delegate.

Comment: It's absolutely normal that GPS doesn't work inside a building. It needs a connection by sight to four satellites to work. Figure out what your application should do if there is no GPS, and write your code accordingly.